# Como configurar um Anonymous Global Scopes no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Dentro da minha model estou utilizando um **Anonymous Global Scopes** para faltar algumas operações:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('owner', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('user_id', 1);
    });
}
```

Mas estou com uma dúvida, na closure acima o valor 'owner' foi colocado no lugar de um argumento chamado scope, no meu caso owner é:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Minha dúvida é, o que de fato deve está presente neste campo definido para scope?

Comment: Qual versão do Laravel e poderia colocar as duas classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes) é recurso contido no `Eloquent` para configurar filtros e restrições para o `Model` em todas as consultas `SQL` que esse modelo faz. Um exemplo é a exclusão lógica ([SoftDelete) que pode ser configurada para qualquer `Model` do `Eloquent` como descrito na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting).

Quando se configura um [Anonymous Global Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes) como exemplo contido na documentação, pode ser configurado uma `classe` ou um `closure`, e se for configurado com um `closure` o primeiro paramento é um texto (***que define um nome qualquer***) e o segundo a função anônima, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Cliente extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'clientes';
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'sobrenome', 'email', 
                           'password', 'ativo'];
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('ativo_filtro', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('ativo',1);
        });
    }
}
```

No código é demonstrado que na `SQL` tem um filtro (`Where`) que só pode trazer os `ativos = 1` ou seja:

```
$clientes = Cliente::all();
```

a `SQL` gerado é

```
"select * from `clientes` where `ativo` = ?"
```

é um recurso que pode ser explorada onde não queira digitar a todo momento um determinado filtro, mas, também existe a forma de inutilizar que é:

removendo um:

```
$cliente = Cliente::withoutGlobalScope('ativo_filtro')->get();
```

removendo vários:

```
$cliente = Cliente::withoutGlobalScopes(['ativo_filtro', '', ...])->get();
```

e removendo todos:

```
$cliente = Cliente::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();
```