# Dúvida de estrutura utilizando Global Scopes no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, scope

Uma dúvida de estrutura.

Cenário: Tenho 3 guards de usuários: administrador, lojas, clientes.

Tenho um model de produtos e quero definir um global scope nele para que quando as lojas acessem a listagem de produtos a query já traga os produtos dessa loja (sem eu precisar ficar passando where na mão em todas as listagens).

Porém se eu definir esse global scope na minha model de produtos vai dar pau quando eu tentar acessar a listagem de produtos geral quando estiver logado no administrador.

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer? Coloco um if no globalscope verificando qual é o usuário que está acessando para saber se eu devo ou nao devo usar esse globalscope, ou entao crio 2 models de produtos e utilizo elas separadamente para cada usuário?

E uma segunda dúvida, se algumas de minhas funções mesmo no usuário da loja não for necessário o uso do global scope, o que eu faço? (sabendo que a maioria das funções sao necessárias o uso).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como configurar um Anonymous Global Scopes no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274713/como-configurar-um-anonymous-global-scopes-no-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se os produtos vão ser sempre filtrados pelo id da loja, então acredito que o corretor seria colocar um global escope mesmo... como a listagem geral é só em um lugar, nessa consulta vc usa o `withoutGlobalScope()`. Ficaria algo assim:

```
Product::withoutGlobalScope(StoreScope::class)->get();
```